# Cancel UIWebView loadRequest

Tags: ios, uiwebview

When I use UIWebView to show a webpage using loadRequest, sometimes it's a time consuming thing when the network not stable, so I want to cancel the loadRequest at will, how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just call

```
[myWebView stopLoading];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stopLoading

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        request.timeoutInterval = 10.0f;
        data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response      error:&connectionError];
```

If during a connection attempt the request remains idle for longer than the timeout interval, the request is considered to have timed out. 
you can detect it and then call [webView stopLoading]